# Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC by writing a double in a formula

Tags: c#, excel

I have a written a program to Auto fill an Excel table like this:

```
A1: 1
A2: =A1+0,5
A3: =A2+0,5
...
```

If `deltaValue` is a number like `1` my program does work fine.
But if `deltaValue` is for example `0.5` my program throws the exception:
`Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC`

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

```
 Excel._Application xlsApp = new Excel.Application();
 xlsApp.Visible = true;

 Excel.Workbook xlsWb = xlsApp.Workbooks.Add();

 double startValue = 0.0;
 double endValue = 0.0;
 double deltaValue = 0.0;

 double.TryParse(txtStartValue.Text, out startValue);
 double.TryParse(txtEndValue.Text, out endValue);
 double.TryParse(txtDeltaValue.Text, out deltaValue);

 xlsWb.Worksheets[1].Range["A1"].value = startValue;
 string temp = string.Format("=R[-1]C+{0}", deltaValue);
 xlsWb.Worksheets[1].Range["A2"].FormulaR1C1 = string.Format("=R[-1]C+{0}", deltaValue);

 double endnumber = (int)(endValue / deltaValue);

 Excel.Range range = xlsWb.Worksheets[1].Range["A2"];

 range.AutoFill(xlsWb.Worksheets[1].Range["A2", string.Format("A{0}", endnumber)], Excel.XlAutoFillType.xlFillDefault);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the lines

```
string temp = string.Format("=R[-1]C+{0}", deltaValue);
xlsWb.Worksheets[1].Range["A2"].FormulaR1C1 = string.Format("=R[-1]C+{0}", deltaValue);
```

with

```
string formula = string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"), @"=R[-1]C+{0:0.0}", deltaValue);
xlsWb.Worksheets[1].Range["A2"].FormulaR1C1 = formula;
```

I was able to reproduce exactly your problem in Excel in Czech language. The Czech language uses `,` character as a decimal point, so when I enter `=R[-1]C+0,5` in Excel it works OK. But when I try do the same via Excel.Interop then I get HRESULT error. So the problem can be solved, if you use allways en-US `.` as a decimal point.

There used to be a rule that `en-US` culture should be used when invoking Excel using COM, so it is perhaps connected with that.

*(Et autant que je suis conscient, la plus belle langue du monde utilise aussi une virgule comme le séparateur décimal.)*